# Get current user ID in Entity Framework Core without having tight coupling

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, entity-framework-core

I have a REST API service which needs to validate any kind of user (for example a Windows user) and add a reference to it into a database table for later usage.

To do so, I need to know the current user in Entity Framework Core, because the user is stored as the creator of an entity.

I am trying to abstract the coupling the current user in the `SaveChanges` method from the `DbContext` where the user is being coupled when an entity is being created.

But how to get the current user in the `DbContext`? I am trying to use delegation, but I am stuck in the way the DI needs to register the `UserService` which abstracts the user and returns the ID.

Comment: typically applications do not create individual users in the database, but use shared connection string for the service/ application and in this case the User of the database is not what you want, instead you want the user of the application. so t get that you are no longer in the ef core area of effect, so do You have users actually created in the database separately ?

Comment: @T.Nielsen I don't want to have the user of the database, but an external user, that is why I need some kind of delegation to get it in the DbContext because the DbContext does not need to know where the user is coming from.

Comment: Some code might help to clarify what you want to do. All I understand is that you want to decouple a user from an unknown source from DbContext (connection string?) but you can't because your UserService is somehow registered in a way that doesn't help and you need the user ID when creating your DbContext... I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think we may need some more detail, but with what is there at least if You are in a .net web api controllerbase context you have

```
System.Security.Principal.IIdentity user = User?.Identity;
if (user != null && user.IsAuthenticated)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Username: {user.Name}");
```

It much depends in this sense which claims tings are put in where you will find what and if you use a completely different authentication scheme things could look different :)

Answer (score 0):

If I had an object

```
public myObj
{
   public int myObjID {get; set;}
   public string ObjectDetails {get; set;}

# I would add this field
   public string UserName {get; set;}

}
```

Then in a controller action where I would store the object, I would do:

```
myObj.UserName = User.Identity?.Name ?? "";
```

The null checking is especially redundant if `[Authorize]` has been applied to the controller because there is no way you can land on the action without being authorized and the application requires that you have a user name (at the barest minimum).

If you ever need to find out who did what:

```
var obj = await db.myObj.where(x=> x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).ToListAsync()
```

or

```
var obj = await db.myObj.where(x=> x.UserName == uname).ToListAsync();
```

*where `uname` is a method argument or etc.*

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking the issue and now I have come up with the following solution:

I have made processor which accepts a number of strategies (in my case for each CRUD operation I have made one strategy to execute). The processor is being invoked when there is a change being made by EF (through `SaveChangesAsync` and `SaveChanges`:

First my `SaveChanges(Asyc)` override:

```cs
     public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
            {
                await _dataOperationProcessor.ProcessAsync(entry, cancellationToken);
            }

            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
```

The processor:

```cs
 public class DataOperationProcessor : IDataOperationProcessor
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IEntityActionStrategy> _entityActionStrategies;   

        public DataOperationProcessor(IEnumerable<IEntityActionStrategy> entityActionStrategies)
        {
            _entityActionStrategies = entityActionStrategies;            
        }

        public void Process(EntityEntry entry)
        {
            foreach (var stategy in _entityActionStrategies.Where(e => e.ForEntityState == entry.State))
            {
                stategy.Execute(entry);
            }
        }

        public async Task ProcessAsync(EntityEntry entry, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var stategy in _entityActionStrategies.Where(e => e.ForEntityState == entry.State))
            {
                await stategy.ExecuteAsync(entry, cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

The strategy which to invoke when an entity is being added:

```cs
public class AuditableEntityCreatedStrategy : BaseEntityActionStrategy<BaseAuditableEntity>
    {
        private readonly IUserAccountInfoResolver _userAccountInfoResolver;

        public AuditableEntityCreatedStrategy(IUserAccountInfoResolver userAccountInfoResolver)
        {
            _userAccountInfoResolver = userAccountInfoResolver;
        }

        public override EntityState ForEntityState => EntityState.Added;

        protected override void ExecuteForType(EntityEntry entry, BaseAuditableEntity entity)
        {
            var userId = _userAccountInfoResolver.ResolveCurrentUser().UserId;         
            var dbUser = (entry.Context as SecurityContext).Users.Single(u => u.UserId == userId);

            entry.CurrentValues[nameof(BaseAuditableEntity.CreatedById)] = dbUser.Id;
            entry.CurrentValues[nameof(BaseAuditableEntity.Created)] = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```